# Counterexample of converse in multivariable Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability

Prove that there exist two real Gaussian distribution $X$ and $Y$ such that the vector $(X,Y)$ is not Gaussian.

The way that i tried to solve this problem was choosing $X=X$, and take before the linear combination $X-X$ or stuff like that; but in the definition of Gaussian distribution that i have the constants are also Gaussians distribution. The statement of this problem (and its generalization) is true if we assume that the constants are Gaussians?

Comment: Take $X$ standard normal and $Y=\epsilon X$ where $\epsilon=\pm1$ is Bernoulli symmetric and independent of $X$. Then $Y$ is standard normal but $(X,Y)$ is not gaussian since $Z=X+Y$ is not normal. To see this, note that $P(Z=0)=P(\epsilon=-1)=\frac12$ while every normal distribution puts mass $0$ or $1$ on the point $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, even if you try with constants, they would just be degenerate normal variables, and a vector composed of constants is itself multivariate normal (even if degenerate).

However such an example can be constructed. Take $Y\sim N(0,1)$ and set, for $a>0$:
$$
X=Y1_{\{|Y|<a\}}-Y1_{\{|Y|>a\}}.
$$
Then the law of $X$ is also $N(0,1)$, but the vector $Z=(Y,X)$ is not multivariate normal, even if its two components are.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another example: Take $X$ and $Y$ to be iid standard normal. Define $U=X+Y$ and $V=sgn(X)\cdot Y$. Then $U\sim\mathcal N(0,2)$, $V\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$, and $U$ and $V$ are uncorrelated. But $U$ and $V$ are not independent: if they were then we would have $\Bbb E[U^2V]=\Bbb E[U^2]\Bbb E[V]=0$, but in fact $\Bbb E[U^2V]=\Bbb E[(X^2+2XY+Y^2)sgn(X)Y]=2\Bbb E|X|\not=0$. It follows that $(U,V)$ is not Gaussian.